# An error occurs in req.login, which is undefined (node passport login error)

Tags: node.js, passport.js

An error occurred while the passport login router logic was running
The login validation was all passed, so the following message was output.

```
console.log("login success !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
```

and After that, an error occurred in req.login

and error message is undefined

```
loginError:::::::::  undefined
```

from back\routes\user.js

```
   return req.login(user, async (loginError) => {
        console.error("loginError::::::::: ", loginError);
        return next(loginError);
    });
```

Thanks for let me know how to fix

below is related code for passport login

login router
back\routes\user.js

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("로그인 라우터 실행 ::::::::::::::::");
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            next(err);
        }
        if (info) { // info가 있다는건 로그인 실패 이유가 생겼다는 것이므로 메세지 리턴 처리 
            console.log("403 에러 발생 ::::::::::: ",info);
            return res.status(403).send(info.reason);
        }
        // 여기까지 로그인 검사 마쳤으면 로그인 시키고 유저 객체 프론트로 반환

        // console.log("user : ", user);

        console.log("login success !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        return req.login(user, async (loginError) => {
            console.error("loginError::::::::: ", loginError);
            return next(loginError);
        });
        return res.json(user);
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

back\passport\index.js

```
const { User } = require('../models');
const passport = require('passport');
const local = require('./local');


module.exports = () => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        console.log("serializerUser 실행 확인 : ", user);
        done(null, user.id); // 로그인 성공시 user.id 를 세션 메모리에 저장 해라 
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id }}); 
            done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            done(error);
        }
    });
    local();
}
```

back\passport\local.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { Strategy: LocalStrategy } = require('passport-local');
const { User } = require('../models');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = () => {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    }, async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({
                where: { email }
            });
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { reason: '존재하지 않는 이메일입니다.' });
            }
            const result = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

            if (result) {
                return done(null, user);
            }
            return done(null, false, { reason: '비밀번호가 틀렸어요' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("로컬 전략에서 에러 발생 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", error);
            console.error(error);
            return done(error);
        }
    }));
}
```

and

About the login method used in the code above
1.Use Passport module
2.Local strategies were established.
3.Routing logic is two steps.
a.Effectiveness test
b.req.login run

[image]

Comment: Once your login has succeeded why you need to pass it to another callback?

Comment: The req.login function should be called successfully because the session and cookie must be set by passport login

Comment: Can you share your login method?

Comment: I used passport login git:https://github.com/hyunsokstar/prepare/tree/master/back
thanks